# If $L>0$ is a partial limit of $a_n$ does $\frac{1}{L}$ is also a partial limit of $a_n$?

Tags: calculus

Given:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_na_{n+1})=1$$
It is known that $a_n$ is bounded from above and contains only positive numbers

Using all this knowledge how can we prove that if $L>0$ is a partial limit of $a_n$ then $\frac{1}{L}$ is also a partial limit of $a_n$?

I thought to just say that if $lim(a_k)=L$ then I can make a subsequence for $a_t=\frac{1}{ak}$ and by so $lim(a_t)=\frac{1}{L}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is a partial limit then for some $n_k$
$$a_{n_k}\to L,\quad k\to\infty.$$

And since $a_n a_{n+1}\to 1$, then $$a_{n_k+1}\to\frac{1}{L}$$

Comment: Oh sorry I think I get it now

Comment: $a_{n_k}a_{n_k+1}\to 1$ and $a_{n_k}\to L$ follows that $$a_{n_k+1} = \frac{a_{n_k}a_{n_k+1}}{a_{n_k}}\to \frac{1}{L}$$